# Data Standards in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This might be a stupid question but i havent been able to find any kind of answers. So im turning to the place where i can always fin an answer. I am using CodeIgniter framework. I was wondering if there is a standard for classes to return data?

Sometimes im returning data as an array (whether it be multi or single dimensional)
Other times i am returning data as an object.

```
$query = $this->db-query($sql);
$result = $query->result(); // returned as object    
foreach( $result as $row)
{
  $row->title
  $row->body
}
```

OR

```
$result = $query->result_array(); //multidimensional array
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $row['title']
  $row['body']
}
```

Which is better for templating? Or what are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use objects as simple container values (although it would probably be easier to use arrays for this). In my opinion, it is mostly up to your personal taste whether to use arrays or standard objects. The only important point, concerning clean code, is to use arrays or objects **consistently** (to avoid unnecessary confusion).

Answer (score 2):

When your object is not a real object but just a disguised array - better make it explicit array.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are **really not** meant as simple containers with public properties while arrays are. Therefore you should go with arrays.

Doesn't really change that much for styling purposes.

Comment: Aren't `stdClass` objects in PHP similar to the `struct` data structures in C, which *are* simple containers?

Comment: @Gargron, yeah, but objects are not meant to store data. Period. Arrays can be easily looped trough via `foreach ($array as $a)` while with an object you would need `foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $a)`, do you see the problem there? You need an hack for almost anything other than accessing a property.

Comment: I think OP was asking about single item's data stored in stdClass vs. stored in a hash, and not where multiple items should be stored.

Comment: @Gargron, I am not talking about multiple items: For example to show all the infos of an object vs all the infos of an array, you would need a loop.

Comment: The scenario of needing to iterate over an item's properties is pretty rare in my experience - usually you know what you are fetching and where to use which properties. The only case where it comes to mind is in displaying table schema phpMyAdmin-style.